# How to encode input data on etherscan when trigger a non open source smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, etherscan

I have deployed a smart contract on Ethereum. When I triggered it, function name and params were displayed on etherscan. How can I hidden these infomation?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5UEU.png)

Comment: Hiding data in a public blockchain is not possible, because by the definition of public everything public.

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan uses a dictionary that translates the function signature to a function name (in your case `0x38ed1739` to `swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)`).

If you don't want them to translate the function name, you'll need to rename your contract functions (it's definition and all places that call them) to some gibberish such as `kdjgklfdjiwefw(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)`.

Be aware that external contracts might want to call your functions by their name that they expect (such as `swapExactTokensForTokens`) and they will not be able to if a function with this name doesn't exist.

If you want to prohibit Etherscan showing the translations but NOT rename your functions - there's currently no way to do that.

Comment: Is the dictionary public?

Comment: @hliu The specific dictionary that Etherscan uses - probably not. But you can make your own by scanning ABI (or source codes) of different contracts.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Scanning all the contracts' source code seems a lot of work:) Does that mean in that way sometimes there may be some newly-created contracts which Etherscan cannot do the mapping to function name because not scanning in time?

Comment: I don't have the data to verify this, but it seems like a possibility.